# Textbox and Table Adapter

Tags: vb.net, dataset, tableadapter

I have a table adapter and it is querying the database base on table id. The result of the query i want to show in textboxes. How can do do that? Some help please.

Answer (score 0):

basically iterate through the Rows of the table then pick the individual cells of each row you want to assign to the textboxes.

A much easier method to display the data, is through the DataGridView, which can bind to the table and show the data automatically.